# hunting a (memory, GC related) heisenbug disappearing without ASLR

Tags: c++, linux, debugging

<sup>OS: Linux/Debian/Sid/x86_64 (and Linux/Debian/Testing/x86_64); my system GCC used for compilation is 6.1.1 (and 5.3 with the Debian/Testing). Gnu libc is 2.22; Linux kernel is 4.5; GDB is system 7.10 or my own, built from FSF source, 7.11</sup>

I am hunting (since nearly two weeks) **a memory & [*garbage collection*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_%28computer_science%29) related [heisenbug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenbug)** in the [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) experimental branch of GCC (MELT is grossly speaking a Lisp-like domain specific language to customize the GCC compiler; the MELT dialect is translated to C++ using MELT itself) which you could retrieve with

```
svn co -r236207 svn://gcc.gnu.org/svn/gcc/branches/melt-branch gcc-melt
```

then (as for every GCC variant or branch) build it in an *outside* tree, e.g.

```
mkdir _ObjMelt
cd _ObjMelt
../gcc-melt/configure  --disable-bootstrap --enable-checks=gc \
 --enable-plugins --disable-multilib --enable-languages=c,c++,lto
```

(you can pass other options to `../gcc-melt/configure`, e.g. `CXXFLAGS='-g3 -O0 -DMELT_HAVE_RUNTIME_DEBUG=1'` if you wanted to; you can remove the `--enable-checks=gc` option)

and of course `make`  (or `make -j4`); that build may take more than half an hour (and will probably fail with ASLR, see below)

MELT has a generational *copying* garbage collector (and I suspect the bug to be a corner case in it) and uses a lot of [metaprogramming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaprogramming) (in particular, most of the scanning and forwarding codes for the copying GC is generated by MELT).

<sup>(`valgrind` won't help here: we are *implementing* a copying GC, and GCC itself is -even without MELT- leaking memory)</sup>

MELT is bootstrapped. The usual build procedure is regenerating twice the emitted C++ code from MELT source code. The usual way is to emit some C++ code, fork some `make` to get a shared object, and `dlopen` that shared object, and again.

*Without* [ASLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization), the build is always succeeding (and it is running a significant test: the bootstrap of MELT, and the analysis of the MELT runtime by a compilation extended by MELT). And I could even regenerate the runtime code with `make upgrade-warmelt`.

But **with ASLR enabled**, the build fails, **crashing** always at in the same fashion (notice that the `cc1plus` is the MELT one):

```
cc1plus: note: MELT got fatal failure from ../../gcc-melt/gcc/melt-runtime.h:900
cc1plus: fatal error: corrupted memory heap with null magic discriminant
                      in 0x2bab6a8; GC#11
compilation terminated.
MELT BUILD SCRIPT FAILURE: 
  melt-build-script.tpl:382/307-melt-build-script.tpl:459/382 failed 
  with arguments @meltbuild-stage2/warmelt-normatch.args
```

I am disabling ASLR e.g. with `exec setarch $(uname -m) -R /bin/bash`; and of course, when running uder `gdb` ASLR is disabled by default (unless I do `set disable-randomization 0` as a GDB command).

My colleague Franck Védrine suggested me to use the [reverse execution](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Reverse-Execution.html) facilities of `gdb`; in principle, it should be as simple as setting a breakpoint in my GC (and in `fatal_error` & `melt_fatal_info` called by the `melt_fatal_error` macro...), reach the `GC#11` state, do a `record` for following backward execution, run the faulty case (with `set disable-randomization 0` to disable ASLR) till the "crash", then `reverse-cont` till the breakpoint in the GC, and use `watch` wisely. Sadly, this triggers a widely **known GDB bug** ([Sourceware#19365](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=19365), [Ubuntu#1573786](http://osdir.com/ml/ubuntu-bugs/2016-04/msg19173.html), [Redhat#1136403](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1136403), ...) - that recent snapshots of GDB like `gdb-7.11.50.20160514` did not correct-

<sup>(I am now tempted to try to avoid that GDB bug, perhaps by having my own `memset` &  `memcpy`  routines with `#pragma GCC optimize ("-Og")`  before them; but that looks going too far)</sup>

For what it is worth, the crashing message is given by the following code (near line 900 of my `melt-runtime.h`):

```
static inline int
melt_magic_discr (melt_ptr_t p)
{
  if (!p)
    return 0;
#if MELT_HAVE_DEBUG > 0 || MELT_HAVE_RUNTIME_DEBUG > 0
  if (MELT_UNLIKELY(!p->u_discr))
    {
      /* This should never happen, we are asking the discriminant of a
      not yet filled, since cleared, memory zone. */
      melt_fatal_error
      ("corrupted memory heap with null discriminant in %p; GC#%ld",
       (void*) p, melt_nb_garbcoll);
    }
#endif /*MELT_HAVE_DEBUG or MELT_HAVE_RUNTIME_DEBUG */
  gcc_assert (p->u_discr != NULL);
  return p->u_discr->meltobj_magic;
}
```

My guess is that the bug might be a difficult GC bug around the forwarding of "discriminant", (a sort of "type" or "class" or "metadata" field in *every* MELT value) in the rare case when that discriminant is still in the young generation ... Adding some code to avoid that indeed made the bug happens later, but I am not sure at all.

**Any clues or advices to debug an heisenbug related to actual virtual addresses (hence sensible to ASLR!) are welcome.**

I even added some initialization code to be able to *optionally* `mmap` or `sbrk`  several useless megabytes, hoping to "reproduce" the randomized address given by `mmap` (called by `calloc` used by MELT and its GC). That did not help yet!

Answer (score 2):

the approach I've been using in my Smalltalk garbage collector is to copy the heap before each GC and execute the GC in the copy, and then repeat to debug if the copy crashes.  This is relatively trivial to do if the system, as mine is, is developed in a high-level oo language; copying the heap is simply copying the graph of objects comprising the VM simulation (and in the simulation the heap is in a single large byte array).

Applying this technique in your context will presumably be considerably more challenging but should not be impossible.  Let me sketch it here...

I'll call the process you're trying to debug the "master" and those that are cloned to try the GC for it children.

Before a GC in the master, do a fork and have the child perform the GC, running a leak checker in the child and exiting with exit status reflecting whether the GC succeeded or not.  The master then proceeds with its own GC if the child's succeeded.  Otherwise it loops, spawning children that repeat the failing GC. You then debug the child.

The child needs to be launched in two states.  The initial launch in each GC simply runs the GC and exits with success status.  Subsequent forks that we now know will fail can enter a wait state so that you can attach gdb to the child.

I call this "lemming debugging", since one can have as many clones jump over the cliff as one needs until the crash is debugged.  Let me know if you get this working.

Comment: I can't say whether Basile will be able to put this technique to good use, but I can say this is a clever technique.